# understanding ruby kEND

Tags: ruby, email

So i'm trying to send an email , and i believe i'm doing almost everything correctly here

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'mail'

Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, address: "localhost", port: 11025
  # smtp 'localhost', 11025 # '10.11.5.164' # Port 25 defult
end

mail = Mail.new do
      from 'me@mydomain.net'
        to 'someone@herdomain.net'
   subject 'TEST'
      body "here the body"
  add_file :filename => 'attachment.html', :content => File.read('/tmp/attachment.html')
end

mail.deliver!
```

But i get:

```
/home/username/personal/ruby/emails/email.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
  delivery_method :smtp, address: "localhost", port: 11025
                                 ^
/home/username/personal/ruby/emails/email.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
  delivery_method :smtp, address: "localhost", port: 11025
```

Any advise? i really cant figure out what i'm doing wrong here since the official Mail documentation points out that the arguments should be colon separated.
I'm using ruby 1.9.3

Thx

Comment: Are you sure in 1.9 ?

Comment: Actually, both on Ruby 1.9 and 2.1, the code you posted passes the syntax check (`ruby -cw`) with no errors or warnings.

Comment: Just to debug `delivery_method :smtp, :address => "localhost", :port => 11025`.. Try this

Comment: I'm **really** sure you are running this code on Ruby 1.8 which doesn't support the new Hash syntax you used. Please check your environment.

Comment: @HolgerJust Same feelings here, thus asked to debug..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using old version of Ruby (probably 1.8?).

The `symbol_name: value` syntax for hash key value pairs is introduced in 1.9. Before then, say in Ruby 1.8, you need to write `:symbol_name => value`.

```
delivery_method :smtp, :address => "localhost", :port => 11025
```

Just like what you have written in your later code.

Comment: @JBoy Did you try what I asked in comment?

Comment: after an upgrade it woked fine with my original code :)